# How can I configure the clipboard of the Google keyboard so that it doesn't delete all items upon phone restart?

Tags: gboard, copy-paste, google-pixel-6

The clipboard of the Google keyboard remove its history upon phone restart. How can I prevent that?

[image]

I use a Google Pixel 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can pin items to the clipboard by pressing and holding them and tapping "Pin" in the pop-up menu.

Restarting will empty the clipboard. Clearing app cache will NOT empty it. Clearing app data *should* clear the clipboard including any pinned items.

It may not be the same on every device. It could be another thing manufacturers can decide. I still have unpinned content in my Gboard clipboard from 10+ hours ago; Moto G Fast on Android 10. There are results online where people say it's removing items after "1-2 hours", but they're over a variety of years on a variety of devices with varying OS and Gboard app versions.

There are alternative Android keyboard apps that have extended clipboard functionality, but of course may lack other features or have even more.